# What do we know of the Willauk, the Tebwem and the Pioial?

Tags: mythical-creatures, indigenous-australian

Wikipedia lists the three creatures as originating in Tasmanian mythology, but other than a very short description it provides no details or references:

> **Tasmania**
>
> - Willauk, giant demon that inhabited Lake Derwent
> - Tebwem, flesh-eating ghost of southern Tasmania
> - Pioial, giant scorpion like creature
>
> <sub>List of Australian Aboriginal mythological figures. (2017, August 13). In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 11:38, September 7, 2017, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Australian_Aboriginal_mythological_figures&oldid=795293807</sub>

A cursory web search revealed no additional information, all references I stumbled upon either point to or regurgitate the linked Wikipedia article.

Do we know of any tales that feature these creatures? Where can I learn more about them?